# Tangent cones at infinity and the regularity of minimal submanifolds

Tags: riemannian-geometry, geometric-measure-theory, geometric-analysis, minimal-surfaces

In the famous paper by D. Fischer-Colbrie "Some rigidity theorems for minimal submanifolds of the sphere", the very first sentence reads: It is well known that the regularity of minimal submanifolds can be reduced to  the study of minimal cones and hence to compact minimal subsminifolds of the sphere.

I understand this might be one of those results relating the so called tangent cones at infinity to cones over compact submanifolds of spheres, but I would like some more clarification.

1. What is the definition of the tangent cone at infinity of a minimal submanifold of dimension $k$ in $\mathbb{R}^{m+k}$? What is precisely the blow down?
2. What is the dimension of this tangent cone at infinity? Under which conditions is this cone smooth outside the tip?
3. What is the definition of the minimal cones (not tangent at infinity) and how do they relate to compact submanifolds of the sphere?
4. I understand the author uses an identification of the tangent cone at infinity of the minimal submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{m+k}$ with the cone over the compact submanifold of $S^{m+k-1}$. But what is the dimension of this compact submanifold so that its cone will "coincide" with the cone at infinity in $\mathbb{R}^{m+k}$?
5. Are there any specific references for that? Such things appear here and there, but I have never seen a proof neither a narrow reference. I have looked and got lost in Federer's book.

I would be very happy if I can understand precisely all these identifications and definitions.

Comment: Presumably Fischer-Colbrie means tangent cones at a singularity not tangent cones at infinity here. It would help if you could clean your question up to ask one specific question. It's a standard fact in GMT that if you blow up at a singular point of a $k$-dimensional minimal surface in $R^{n+k}$ you converge to a stationary integral $k$-dimensional varifold in $R^{n+k}$ that's invariant under dilation. In general, this varifold will be very singular. But you can regard it as a varifold cone over a $k-1$-dimensional stationary integral varifold in $S^{n+k-1}$.

Comment: So if your question is just, what's the dimension of the tangent cone at a singularity, it's the same as the dimension of the minimal surface.

Comment: @OtisChodosh: Thanks for the reply. Maybe my question is not really about the dimension, I think I wanted just to confirm it is the same dim. It is really about the definition of the tangent cone at a singularity as you say, also of the tangent cone at infinity, since I keep encountering this expression here and there but never the precise definition and more importantly: where can I read the proofs of these "standard facts of GMT"?

Comment: Another thing, by a blow up do you simply mean multiplying the metric of the manifold by some r_i that goes to infinity as i grows?

Comment: A good reference is Leon Simons GMT, in the typewriter (1st edition) version you can see Theorem 19.3.

Comment: It's easiest to understand things in Euclidean space where you are essentially just rescaling the minimal surface/varifold around the fixed point. In a manifold you indeed need to rescale the metric but I think this will introduce an additional confusion for you that's not worth it yet.

Comment: @OtisChodosh, thank you, this theorem 19.3 was very helpful, indeed he proves there that the limiting object is a cone as you said. Well, I still have to read a lot there because I am new to the topic to understand things fully. Does he also speak at some point about this relation with the varifold cone over a k-1 dim stationary varifold in $S^{n+k-1}$?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not sure that he does and I am not sure that I know a basic reference for this. Sorry! You might try to work this out for yourself. Basically, you should see what formula you expect to hold and then use this to define the varifold in the sphere. Then check that things agree as you expect.